# Using isinstance() during exception handling for subsequent action

Tags: design, object-oriented, python

I've read various posts that polymorphism should be used instead of `isinstance`, and I agree that makes sense when the use of `isinstance` is checking the subtypes of a class to determine what to do. However, is the use of `isinstance` acceptable when checking the type of an object in order to do something unrelated to the object itself?

For exammple:

```
last_little_err = last_big_err = None

for thing in things:
    try:
        thing.dothing()
    except (LittleError, BigError) as err:
        logger.error(err, extra={'thingObj': thing.name})
        if isinstance(err, LittleError):
            last_little_err = err
        else:
            last_big_err = err
    else:
        thing.success = True

if last_big_err is not None:
    raise SuperBigError('A big thing error occurred') from last_big_err
elif last_little_err is not None:
    display_error_warning(last_little_err)
```

I believe using `isinstance` here is fine since I am not defining what the objects should do *based on their type* but rather checking their type to determine which variable should store it for later use. Is my reasoning valid?

Comment: This is kinda strange, why do you want to catch this error and save it to a variable? If `things[0].dothing()` fails, your loop will keep going and keep trying to `dothing()` on the rest of the things. Is this international?

Comment: @Alexander Yes. These are "pass-fail" actions that do not impact the execution of the application, but each should at least be attempted. Any of them can fail, and should be logged, with only the last failure being captured and displayed; handled differently if a known large failure (the `raise`).

Comment: And you only ever care about a single error, even if there are many?

Comment: @Alexander Correct. Its for logging purposes only. The system tries to repair some things, if they fail thats fine (unless its a big known failure).

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a case when ruthlessly eliminating code duplication causes other problems. If you cannot treat `LittleError` and `BigError` the same, do not handle them the same way. The `if` statement in the `except` block is a big red flag that these exception types should be handled differently. They do have similar elements, that is both should set the success flag to `True`. But this would be better just catching both exception types on their own with a duplicate call to set the success flag:

```py
try:
    thing.dothing()
except LittleError as err1:
    logger.error(err1, extra={'thingObj': thing.name})
    last_little_err = err1
except BigError as err2
    logger.error(err2, extra={'thingObj': thing.name})
    last_big_err = err2
else:
    thing.success = True
```

The code repetition is minimal. The code is easy to read. No need to infer the exception type. I find eliminating code duplication inside exception handlers to be more difficult for precisely the reason you posted this question. I've learned a little code duplication in exception handlers goes a long way towards making exception handling a little clearer. The more obvious you make your failure handling code, the better off your application will be.

Comment: Does this abide with DRY guidelines though? Doing exactly the same thing in each block.

Comment: @madeslurpy: DRY is a guideline, not a law. Abide by guidelines when they make your life easier. DRY does not make exception handling easier, so don't feel like you need to abide by DRY.

Comment: [*"duplication is far cheaper than the wrong abstraction"*](https://sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction)

Comment: @jonrsharpe But is using `isinstance()` an abstraction? I'm not pulling anything out to its own method, there is no passing of anything or altering of arguments as described in that article.

Comment: @madeslurpy, if you want to make those exception handlers DRY, refactor the common parts into a new function and call that from the exception handlers.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau So DRY is not necessarily duplicating/calling the same function in multiple places, but rather reimplementing the same logic each time?

Comment: @madeslurpy, YES. DRY is all about having the same logic only in one place, so that you only have to update one place if a modification is needed (due to a bug or a change request).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The only shared logic in this case would be the logging call; the example provided in the answer is erroneous because `thing.success` would not be called in the exception handlers. Is that worth abstracting?

Comment: @madeslurpy, A single function call (logging or otherwise) is not worth it to abstract further. With logging, there is even the chance that it is not really duplicated but only appears to be. It is possible that at some point in the future you want to log slightly different things for `BigError` and `LittleError` so you can differentiate the two when looking at the logs.

Comment: @madeslurpy: there is a little bit of duplicate logic there now in *how* the logger is used precisely. This might be worth to be extracted into a single function, or not. My rule here: if you are in doubt, next time you come to this place again for changing something, and you notice you would have to make the same change to the logging call two times, refactor the logic into a separate function beforehand, so you have to change only one place.

Comment: @DocBrown Where would you place the call to the abstracted method? In each `except` block or in the `finally` block perhaps?

Comment: @GregBurghardt: I think this answer is missing  Bart van Ingen Schenau's recommendation from the above comments. Telling people they should generally throw all DRY rules over board in exception handling is IMHO unbalanced.

Comment: @madeslurpy: in each `except` block, of course, if you don't want to change the semantics of your example.